# Keyframes not animating object

Tags: animation, keyframes

When I try to key frame a plane it indicates with the yellow bar on the timeline that I have set the key frame, but as soon as I go to set another key frame or play the animation the yellow bar remains but the object goes back to normal.
When I play the animation the object is idle as if there is no key frame. I have already searched a while on the web for this and found something on it but it had no solution.

Comment: What did you keyframe? You may have keyframed rotation instead of location for example

Comment: Please add more information or make your file available to download. So far we can't tell what is going on without knowing what you've done. Is the key frame to  move, scale, rotate, deform? What do you mean by "going back to normal?"

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand, but I believe I am answering.

It being a plane should not make a difference.

It sounds like you need to add another keyframe. If I am interpreting your question correctly, you are inserting a keyframe, moving/rotating/scaling the plane, relocating the time cursor, and watching all of your transformations revert to the keyframed loc/rot/scale. You can animate by inserting that original keyframe, NEXT moving the time cursor, changing the loc/rot/scale, and finally keyframing again. The plane should now change it's loc/rot/scale between the two keyframes.

Comment: no im afraid the problem is not that what happens is that i set the first keyframe to the pose that it is already to initiate the move or scale in this place then i go to set a second keyframe the object reverts to original pose and does not move when i hit play

Answer (score 0):

I'm only answering this old question because I discovered my own fix so anyone looking in the future can answer it here. I had the same issue after loading a days old project. All I had to do was individually click each keyframe choice I needed. I needed scale, rotation, and location. So by clicking each one individually instead of just "i", while mousing over the viewport, it worked and started animating like normal.