# Animated Property Ignores Keyframes

Tags: animation

I am animating a character walking down a path for a short project, using the fixed position and animating the offset. However, the animation is ignored. I can still manually move the slider, and the background works, but the offset doesn't change. What can cause this behavior? Similar to [Keyframes not animating object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51907/keyframes-not-animating-object), but that doesn't help.

[image]